# In the life of a bond future contract, can a bond be removed from the delivery basket?

Tags: bond, bond-futures

It is clear that a bond can be added to the delivery basket in the life of a contract. For example, a new issuance. But can a bond be removed from a basket?

Comment: If a bond was repurchased by an issuer, this would amount to removing it. Practically speaking a bond can remain in the delivery basket as per contract spec but not be practically available for consideration if the free float is zero and is impossible to deliver.

Comment: Just thinking out loud, in the past, when USD interest rates were much higher, the US used to issue callable treasuries. CME/CBOT's US treasuriy futures specifications  https://www.cmegroup.com/content/dam/cmegroup/rulebook/CBOT/II/18.pdf explicitly exclude them after the first call dates. Some other countries also have treasury bond futures with cheapest to deliver. I'm guessing that a cheapest to deliver calculations there may need to check whether a bond can still be delivered, or is all gone.